# Understanding QVector append() - Why does it copy conditionally?

Tags: c++, qt, reference, qvector

Here is the implementation of QVector's append() from [github](https://github.com/qt/qt/blob/0a2f2382541424726168804be2c90b91381608c6/src/corelib/tools/qvector.h):

```
template <typename T>
void QVector<T>::append(const T &t)
{
    if (d->ref != 1 || d->size + 1 > d->alloc) {
        const T copy(t);
        realloc(d->size, QVectorData::grow(sizeOfTypedData(), d->size + 1, sizeof(T),
                                           QTypeInfo<T>::isStatic));
        if (QTypeInfo<T>::isComplex)
            new (p->array + d->size) T(copy);
        else
            p->array[d->size] = copy;
    } else {
        if (QTypeInfo<T>::isComplex)
            new (p->array + d->size) T(t);
        else
            p->array[d->size] = t;
    }
    ++d->size;
}
```

Why does it need to make a copy of `t` if the number of references to the vector != 1 or it needs to resize and why does it make a copy only for these conditions?

A related question has been asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30790817/qvectorappend-what-reason-for-explicit-copying), but in the code there a copy of `t` is always made before appending to the underlying array.

Comment: The second condition (it needs to resize) is most likely to avoid destroying an objects due to the resize for which a copy is meant to be appended: if `t` is a reference to an element in the vector it would be invalidated before it is added. I don't know about the other conditiion.

Comment: It's an interesting implementation choice. From looking at MSVC implementation of `std::vector::push_back()`, they don't make a temporary copy of the passed value like this. Instead they first allocate new array (without destroying old one), copy-construct the value at the end of the new array and only after that deallocate the old array. Seems to be more efficient.

Comment: @zett42, do you mean MSVC's implementation is more efficient?
 If so can you elaborate why and how much more efficient it would be?

Comment: Just for the record: Qt's QVector is an implicitly shared container and because of that there is the "d->ref != 1" check (copy-on-write).

Answer (score 4):

At a quick glance it is probably because the `if` part is for when the vector reallocates whereas the `else` part is for when it doesn't. When it does reallocate the user could have done `vector.append(vector[index])` in which case `t` would become invalid after the reallocation, therefore a copy must be made before reallocating. In the `else` part without a reallocation `t` will stay valid and no copy is necessary.